# How do I make multiple if conditions, that returns true, execute in C#?

Tags: c#, if-statement, checkedlistbox

I have a checkedListBox where the user can select whatever they want to update. I want them to be able to freely update 1 up to 5 characteristics of a machine. So when they only want to update 1 thing, they do not have to provide the other 4 characteristics. Also, when they want to update 5 characteristics, they
can do it in one go. For that purpose I have the following if statements:

```
if (clbCharacteristicsToUpdate.CheckedItems.Count != 0)
{
                        if (clbCharacteristicsToUpdate.GetSelected(0))
                        {
                            currentITime = Convert.ToDouble(tbCurrentITime.Text);
                            MessageBox.Show(currentITime.ToString());
                            dh.UpdateCurrentITime(machineNr, currentITime);
                        }
                        if (clbCharacteristicsToUpdate.GetSelected(1))
                        {
                            cycleTime = Convert.ToDouble(tbCycleTime.Text);
                            MessageBox.Show(cycleTime.ToString());
                            dh.UpdateCycleTime(machineNr, cycleTime);
                        }
                        if (clbCharacteristicsToUpdate.GetSelected(2))
                        {
                            nrOfLinesPerCm = Convert.ToInt32(tbNrOfLinesPerCm.Text);
                            MessageBox.Show(nrOfLinesPerCm.ToString());
                            dh.UpdateNrOfLinesPerCm(machineNr, nrOfLinesPerCm);
                        }
                        if (clbCharacteristicsToUpdate.GetSelected(3))
                        {
                            heightOfLamallae = Convert.ToDouble(tbHeightOfLamallae.Text);
                            MessageBox.Show(heightOfLamallae.ToString());
                            dh.UpdateHeightOfLamallae(machineNr, heightOfLamallae);
                        }
                        if (clbCharacteristicsToUpdate.GetSelected(4))
                        {
                            if (rbLTB.Checked)
                            {
                                machineType = 2;
                                MessageBox.Show(machineType.ToString());
                            }
                            else if (rbSTB.Checked)
                            {
                                machineType = 1;
                                MessageBox.Show(machineType.ToString());
                            }
                            if(!rbLTB.Checked && !rbSTB.Checked)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Select a machine type to update!");
                                return;
                            }
                            dh.UpdateType(machineNr, machineType);  
                         }

}
```

My problem is that, when I choose and update 1 thing it works perfectly. But when I choose multiple ones, it only executes the last if statement that returns true. I thought about using if-else but then only the first one that returns true will be executed. I also thought about having if statements for each possibility. But since I have 5 characteristics I can update, this would make 25 possibilities and I do not want to have 25 if statements. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take out the elses. Just if a, if b, if c...

Comment: What are the `if`s you are talking about? Do you have a bug or you don't know how to do a change?

Comment: @pm100 can you be more specific?

Comment: Create a method to check conditions and execute as needed. CheckedItems is a collection, do a foreach and call that method.

Comment: @aamartin2k how do i write the foreach statement? I tried ```foreach(CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection checkedlb in clbCharacteristicsToUpdate.CheckedItems)``` but it gave me an error saying it cannot cast System.string to CheckedItemCollection.

Answer (score 3):

`GetSelected` does not check whether the item has been checked, but that it is actually selected.
For example, in the below image "Item 2" will will return true for `GetSelected`. It is *selected*, not *checked*.

[image: checkedlistbox]

Instead you could do something like checking the `clbCharacteristicsToUpdate.CheckedItems` property to get the items that are actually checked.

The [GetSelected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.getselected?view=netcore-3.1) method actually comes from the `ListBox` class, which `CheckedListBox` inherits from.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
This is a helper method I created on a button.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckList();
}
```

This method looks if items are checked and iterates over the collection of checked ones, calling the last metod.

```
private void CheckList()
{
    if (clbCharacteristicsToUpdate.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (int indexChecked in clbCharacteristicsToUpdate.CheckedIndices)
        {
            CheckSelectedItem(indexChecked);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, here the appropriate actions are taken based on indexes.

```
private void CheckSelectedItem(int index)
{
    if (index == 0)
    {
        //Do stuff on Zero
        MessageBox.Show("Zero");
    }

    if (index == 3)
    {
        //Do stuff on One
        MessageBox.Show("Three");  
    }
}
```